# Excel/VBA - Updating SUMPRODUCT (and other) selectors when in Solver Loop

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a program in Excel that tries to maximize the sum of set of values, constrained by keeping a variable X (whose values are tied to each value being summed), under a specific threshold value.  It has to do this over 66 datasets (across 66 columns).

I don't quite understand how to apply column offset to the `SUMPRODUCT` I see in the VBA prompt or the Solver selection.  Basically, I need to understand how to code in VBA to offset the selection within the `SUMPRODUCT` by one row to the right with each iteration [Explanatory pic of what I need VBA to do each iteration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WseQq.png).  I also have a similar problem iterating the Solver selection cells to the right, I don't quite understand the syntax needed.  Ex: SolverAdd `CellRef:="$C$28:$C$38"`, whereby the next iteration would be interpreted as `SolverAdd CellRed:="$D$28:$D$28"`, and so on.

My code so far looks like this!  I know I'll need to add in the iteration using 'i' to the lines containing `SUMPRODUCT`, but I'm having trouble interpreting what everything within the `SUMPRODUCT` brackets refers to, and where to add in the "horizontal by one" offset.

Let me know if I forgot to include anything obvious here :)

Thanks in advance,

Paul

```
For i = 0 To 66 ' PesticideMacro Macro '

    SolverReset

    Range("N5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=SUMPRODUCT(RC[-4]:R[10]C[-4],R[23]C[-11]:R[33]C[-11])"
    Range("O5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
       "=SUMPRODUCT(R[41]C[-12]:R[51]C[-12],R[23]C[-12]:R[33]C[-12])/SUMPRODUCT(RC[-5]:R[10]C[-5],R[23]C[-12]:R[33]C[-12])*1000000"
    Range("C27").Offset(0, i).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("P5").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$C$28:$C$38", Relation:=5
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$O$5", Relation:=1, FormulaText:="$P$5"
    SolverOk SetCell:="$N$5", MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$C$28:$C$38", _
     Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverSolve (True)
    SolverSolve userFinish:=True
    SolverFinish KeepFinal:=1

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: please reformat your question it is hardly readable

Comment: Bump, still need help :)